# "cannot convert from gameObject to Transform" I think its a simple fix but I'm still trying to pin the fix precisely, any ideas?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm in the process of writing the c# code for the multiplayer that's being implemented into my game me and my friends are working on and I've run into the following error: "Assets\Scripts\Multiplayer\Launcher.cs(99,43): error CS1503: Argument 2: cannot convert from 'UnityEngine.GameObject' to 'UnityEngine.Transform'"

I believe its complaining about these lines of code which are supposed to control part of the multiplayer lobby:

```
public override void OnRoomListUpdate(List<RoomInfo> roomList)
{
    foreach(Transform trans in roomListContent)
    {
        Destroy(trans.gameObject);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < roomList.Count; i++)
    {
        Instantiate(RoomListItemPrefab, roomListContent).GetComponent<RoomListItem>().SetUp(roomList[i]);
    }
}

public override void OnPlayerEnteredRoom(Player newPlayer)
{
    Instantiate(PlayerListItemPrefab, playerListContent).GetComponent<PlayerListItem>().SetUp(newPlayer);
}
```

}

Comment: What do you mean by `I believe` .. ? What is line `99`, character `43` ? the error is telling you the exact place where the error is thrown

Answer (score 0):

Such error message simply means you are passing an argument of the wrong type. In this case most likely it's complaining the second arg to `Instantiate()` it should be a `Transform` but is a `GameObject`. Hard to say for sure because you didn't even post the full source code. What's the type of `playerListContent` ?

Answer (score 0):

As said by gregee, it is hard to know exactly the problem here but it is likely that `playerListContent` is not of type `gameObject`. When giving instantiate two parameters, as you are, they must fit specific types that will change based on the total number of parameters you are giving. In this case:

```
Instantiate(Object original, Transform parent)
```

Meaning that `playerListContent` should be a transform to parent the instantiated object too.